# How to give dynamic value to @Table(name=p+"name") in spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

name of the table should be fixed but in my scenario the last part of the table name is profile based so in local it is X but in dev it is Y and so on till Prod. Is there way to add dynamically the value to the table name.

Comment: Not possible as of now.

Comment: That's why you have `orm.xml` so you can specify schema info in meta files (rather than the weird idea of hardcoding in annotations), and have different `orm.xml` for different environment ... And that is the JPA API, not "Spring Data JPA"

Comment: You are right but the question arises when we are going to use JdBcTemplate jar , I can have the query which will have the dynamic table name, just trying to understand what is the advantage of having JPA to the JdbcTemplate

Answer (score 1):

The question tries to implement a bad practice. Don't do that.

Currently, Spring, Hibernate, and JPA does not support your configuration type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate interceptors to change the table in the generated SQL statements.

For your case you can define your table class like this:

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy(lazy=false)
@Table(name=TableNameReplacer.PLACEHOLDER, schema="MySchema")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class ProfileData implements Serializable {
```

and define your Hibernate interceptor in a following way:

```
public class TableNameReplacer extends EmptyInterceptor {

    public static final String TABLE_PLACEHOLDER = "{table_placeholder}";

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        if (sql.contains(TABLE_PLACEHOLDER )) {
            String replacement = "{your logic to fill proper table name}";


            sql = sql.replace(TABLE_SUFFIX_PLACEHOLDER, replacement);
        }

        return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
    }
```

Using this approach you're free to modify generated SQL and replace the table name there as you wish.

I recommend to use good placeholder value which you're sure will not be a part of actual values being saved to the table (or you can only limit this to select statements if you only read the data).